# Panel data: create new variable upon mutiple and complicate conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im a stata user and im trying to pass my code into python. I am dealing with the following problem, i want to create a new variable called `jobs_t5` which shows the jobs that the `id` has for the following 5 years whenever the following conditions is sastify `df.year==df.cohort` and `df.cohort <= 2013`

Example pass from this dataframe:

```
id  year  entry  cohort  jobs  year_of_life  
1  2009    0     NaN      10      NaN         
1  2012    1     2012     12      0            
1  2013    0     2012     12      1
1  2014    0     2012     13      2
1  2015    0     2012     15      3
1  2016    0     2012     17      4
1  2017    0     2012     18      5
2  2009    1     2009     15      0 
2  2010    0     2009     2       1
2  2011    0     2009     3       2
2  2012    0     2009     3       3
2  2013    0     2009     15      4 
2  2014    0     2009     12      5
2  2015    0     2009     13      6
2  2016    0     2009     13      7
```

into:

```
id  year  entry  cohort  jobs  year_of_life  jobs_t5
1  2009    0     NaN      10      NaN         NaN
1  2012    1     2012     12      0           18       
1  2013    0     2012     12      1           NaN
1  2014    0     2012     13      2           NaN
1  2015    0     2012     15      3           NaN
1  2016    0     2012     17      4           NaN
1  2017    0     2012     18      5           NaN
2  2009    1     2009     15      0           12
2  2010    0     2009     2       1           NaN
2  2011    0     2009     3       2           NaN
2  2012    0     2009     3       3           NaN
2  2013    0     2009     15      4           NaN
2  2014    0     2009     12      5           NaN
2  2015    0     2009     13      6           NaN
2  2016    0     2009     13      7           NaN
```

Comment: df.anio can not find it via your sample data

Comment: @Wen See my answer, I think it's what OP is looking for.

Comment: Let me know if the answer wasn't helpful. You could ask for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, now i will try it on my pc work, i dont understand the last part [df.year==df.cohort], gives a result of booleans of true and false ? it's like and "if" classic command in stata?

Comment: Already understand @CoLdSpeed, Thank you very much!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ there is any handbook with pandas-python-numpy of data analysis which you recommend me?

Comment: Yes, it gives a Boolean mask.

Comment: Hmm, the only way I learned was by answering question.ms. However I would recommend “10 Minutes to Pandas”, take at least 30 mins to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant to compare `year` to `cohort`, you can shift `jobs` up by 5 spots and then just index and assign.

```
df['jobs_t5'] = df.jobs.shift(-5)[df.year == df.cohort]    
df

    id  year  entry  cohort  jobs  year_of_life  jobs_t5
0    1  2009      0     NaN    10           NaN      NaN
1    1  2012      1  2012.0    12           0.0     18.0
2    1  2013      0  2012.0    12           1.0      NaN
3    1  2014      0  2012.0    13           2.0      NaN
4    1  2015      0  2012.0    15           3.0      NaN
5    1  2016      0  2012.0    17           4.0      NaN
6    1  2017      0  2012.0    18           5.0      NaN
7    2  2009      1  2009.0    15           0.0     12.0
8    2  2010      0  2009.0     2           1.0      NaN
9    2  2011      0  2009.0     3           2.0      NaN
10   2  2012      0  2009.0     3           3.0      NaN
11   2  2013      0  2009.0    15           4.0      NaN
12   2  2014      0  2009.0    12           5.0      NaN
13   2  2015      0  2009.0    13           6.0      NaN
14   2  2016      0  2009.0    13           7.0      NaN
```

Comment: great answer, now i am gonna posta a difficult question (intresting for doing data analysis), i hope you can help as you always helped me !

Comment: the post name is "Panel data: transition matrix for firms"